# Column of BIT datatype is not inserting/updating default values in MySql database using Spring Boot

Tags: mysql, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

So I have a table which is configured something like this

```
    CREATE TABLE `jobDetails` (
  `id` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `job_id` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `editor_id` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `editor_dueDate` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `ops_tags` int NOT NULL DEFAULT '2',
  `notes_from_ops` text CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci,
  `reviewer_id` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `reviewer_dueDate` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `sales_tags` varchar(255) DEFAULT '13',
  `notes_from_sales` text CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci,
  `shift` int DEFAULT NULL,
  `additionalNotes` text CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci,
  `editorStatus` int DEFAULT NULL,
  `tracked_file_id` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `clean_file_id` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `additional_file_id` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `editor_wordCount` int DEFAULT NULL,
  `job_details_type` int DEFAULT '0',
  `editing_speed` int DEFAULT '0',
  `reviewing_priority` int DEFAULT NULL,
  `is_enabled` bit(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT b'1',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `FKhb282r593ce4xojoo4hfd3fwm` (`additional_file_id`),
  KEY `FKnb8b8nhc9yb78e2p5ipadfc8u` (`clean_file_id`),
  KEY `FK82594hccbyjik7bc0ev4f74ks` (`tracked_file_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK82594hccbyjik7bc0ev4f74ks` FOREIGN KEY (`tracked_file_id`) REFERENCES `files` (`id`) ON DELETE RESTRICT ON UPDATE RESTRICT,
  CONSTRAINT `FKhb282r593ce4xojoo4hfd3fwm` FOREIGN KEY (`additional_file_id`) REFERENCES `files` (`id`) ON DELETE RESTRICT ON UPDATE RESTRICT,
  CONSTRAINT `FKnb8b8nhc9yb78e2p5ipadfc8u` FOREIGN KEY (`clean_file_id`) REFERENCES `files` (`id`) ON DELETE RESTRICT ON UPDATE RESTRICT
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

So when I insert/update into this table through my code without setting its value then it should consider a default value to "true" or "1", but currently this is not the case it sets the value to "0" or "false".

My backend is using Spring Boot and Spring Data JPA

Comment: You should post also your relavant code, the entity in particular.

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing your code might be difficult to answer, but here's a theory: you are (auto)initializing primitives (`int` or `boolean`) with their default value (`0` or `false`), which is not `null`, so the `DEFAULT` keyword is ignored. You should also define default column values in Java, as shown [here](https://www.baeldung.com/jpa-default-column-values).